# Any way to make a checkbox able to be 'tabbed' to on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, html

On a computer you can easily tab through HTML checkboxes on a website, but is there any way to make it so that on an iPhone when you hit the 'next' button it goes to a checkbox? I've noticed it'll go between text boxes and drop down menus, but it won't do it for checkboxes or clickable buttons.  Is this an issue with the iPhone, or is it something I can change on my website?

Answer (score -1):

Can you please be a bit more precise with your question. And if its the size of the checkbox that is a concern which makes it non tappable, then as suggested by the user interface guide of apple ios, please make the size as 44x44 to make it tappable. Well thats just a suggestible size and I believe a 25x25 size may solve your issue.

Comment: The question isn't whether a check box can be tapped on, it is whether it can be selected by hitting the 'next' button.

Comment: well in that case. if its a website that you are doing, then its not an issue with the iPhone as such. as iPhone merely renders html page as it is. You might wanna check your website script once for mobile platforms. I hope that would help you.

Comment: To be a little more precise, if I go to the website on a PC, click a text box, and then repeatedly hit tab, I will tab through textboxes, checkboxes, buttons, etc. Basically every kind of input can be 'tabbed' to on a desktop/computer. However when I try to access the site with an iPhone, I can only scroll through textboxes and drop down menu's with the 'next' button, but it will never select a checkbox, radio button, and some other HTML input types. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: The way i get it is that, text-boxes and buttons can be identified by iPhone, perhaps thats why it goes to them when next button is pressed. where as there are no controls such as checkbox or radiobuttons thus it fails to identify their tab indexes. have you tried the website on other platforms such as android and do they simulate the same behavior?